# concatenate array to string from firestore

Tags: java, android, string, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing some data in Firestore which looks as follows:

[image]

I had like now to get this data and create a single string as:

```
David John Josh
```

Separated with space in between the words.

I get this data by using:

```
queryNames.get().addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
        for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.size(); i++){
            String Names = snapshot.getDocuments().get( i ).get( "Names" ) );
        }
        if (snapshot.isEmpty()){

        }

    }
} );
```

How can I concatenate this words for a single string?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the `Names` field from the document, you get back an array or `List`.

So you can iterate over that and concatenate the individual strings/names with:

```
queryNames.get().addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
            // Get the list of names from the document
            List<String> namesList = (List<String>) document.get("Names");

            // Concatenate all the names into a single string
            String names = String.join(", ", namesList)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Used TextUtils.join(" ", namesList) and it did the job. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate all the names together.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.size(); i++){
    if(i != 0) sb.append(' ');
    String name= snapshot.getDocuments().get( i ).get( "Names" ) ;
    sb.append(name);
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how works Firestore, but if you need to concatenate, then you can do something like that:

```
queryNames.get().addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.size(); i++){
            result += snapshot.getDocuments().get( i ).get( "Names" ) ) + " ";
        }
        if (snapshot.isEmpty()){

        }
    }
} );
```

Alternatively, you could:

- Use a StringBuilder instead of java concatenation.
- Store the data in a `List<String>` and use `list.stream.collect(Collectors.joining(" "))`